# Python PyQt5 change items in listWidget in accordace to the value in comboBox

Tags: python, python-3.x, combobox, pyqt5

I am using PyQt5 (since this is the default PyQt available in Anaconda) to develop a GUI for my Python program.

Here is the screenshot:

[image]

In the comboBox there are four values: option 1, option 2, option 3, and option 4. I am aiming to change the items listed in the listWidget in accordance to the value in the comboBox. For example, if I change the value in the comboBox to "Option 2", the items in the listWidget should change to "Option 2 00", "Option 2 01", and so forth until the end of the loop. However, so far my attempts return no luck.

[image]

So far here is my code:

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

class Ui_Dialog(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.lst = ['Option 1', 'Option 2', 'Option 3', 'Option 4']

    def _add_items_to_listWidget(self, text):
        for i in range(30):
            item=QtWidgets.QListWidgetItem()
            name= text+' %02d'%i
            item.setText(name)                        
            self.listWidget.addItem(item)

    def setupUi(self, Dialog):
        Dialog.setObjectName("Dialog")
        Dialog.resize(240, 320)
        self.comboBox = QtWidgets.QComboBox(Dialog)
        self.comboBox.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 20, 221, 22))
        self.comboBox.setObjectName("comboBox")
        self.comboBox.addItems(self.lst)

        self.listWidget = QtWidgets.QListWidget(Dialog)
        self.listWidget.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 60, 221, 241))
        self.listWidget.setObjectName("listWidget")
        self.listWidget.setSelectionMode(QtWidgets.QAbstractItemView.ExtendedSelection)
        self._add_items_to_listWidget(str(self.comboBox.currentText()))

        self.retranslateUi(Dialog)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(Dialog)

    def retranslateUi(self, Dialog):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        Dialog.setWindowTitle(_translate("Dialog", "Dialog"))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    Dialog = QtWidgets.QDialog()
    ui = Ui_Dialog()
    ui.setupUi(Dialog)
    Dialog.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

This is my first time working with GUI, so I have very limited knowledge in this regard. Thanks a lot. Any advice will be much appreciated.

Regards,

Arnold

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to add the following signal and method.

```
    self.comboBox.currentIndexChanged.connect(self.selectionchange)

def selectionchange(self,i):
    self.listWidget.clear() 
    self._add_items_to_listWidget(str(self.comboBox.currentText()))
```

Like this:

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

class Ui_Dialog(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.lst = ['Option 1', 'Option 2', 'Option 3', 'Option 4']

    def _add_items_to_listWidget(self, text):
        for i in range(30):
            item=QtWidgets.QListWidgetItem()
            name= text+' %02d'%i
            item.setText(name)                        
            self.listWidget.addItem(item)

    def setupUi(self, Dialog):
        Dialog.setObjectName("Dialog")
        Dialog.resize(240, 320)
        self.comboBox = QtWidgets.QComboBox(Dialog)
        self.comboBox.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 20, 221, 22))
        self.comboBox.setObjectName("comboBox")
        self.comboBox.addItems(self.lst)
        self.comboBox.currentIndexChanged.connect(self.selectionchange)

        self.listWidget = QtWidgets.QListWidget(Dialog)
        self.listWidget.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 60, 221, 241))
        self.listWidget.setObjectName("listWidget")
        self.listWidget.setSelectionMode(QtWidgets.QAbstractItemView.ExtendedSelection)
        self._add_items_to_listWidget(str(self.comboBox.currentText()))

        self.retranslateUi(Dialog)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(Dialog)

    def retranslateUi(self, Dialog):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        Dialog.setWindowTitle(_translate("Dialog", "Dialog"))

    def selectionchange(self,i):
        self.listWidget.clear() 
        self._add_items_to_listWidget(str(self.comboBox.currentText()))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    Dialog = QtWidgets.QDialog()
    ui = Ui_Dialog()
    ui.setupUi(Dialog)
    Dialog.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

gives:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot! It works like a charm! Once again, thank you so much!